# Blob inside JSON object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have problems trying to store data from **Blob** object into a **JSON** object with **Javascript**. This is the case:

I can get the Blob objetc from a image file:

```
var blob = new Blob([readerImageReal.result], {type: "image/png"}); 
var img = document.getElementById("attachmentsImg");
img.onload = function () {
    drawImage(img); //displays the image in html <img src='blob:...'></img>
};
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file); //File from e.target.files[0]
```

But i dont know how to **get Blob data** to send it to a server **inside a JSON object**. I'm trying:

```
var jsonImages = {};
jsonData['images'] = [];
jsonImages['image_real'] = $('#img').attr('src');
jsonData['images'].push(jsonImages);
```

But Blob src is not data (its only an uri string). How can i store blob data inside JSON object, to send it to a Java server? I want the image with Blob (no Base 64 for example), and i need **extract data** from the image.

Comment: Try this example: http://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/edaf09b84185418a55d9 
It does just what you need, gets blob data from img element. Then you can store it in jsonData object and send it to server.

Comment: I cant see blob data. I know URL.createObjectURL(blob), but i want to insert blob data into json onject. I dont know blob-util can be useful. I think it should be much easier. Now is working with base 64 but i want to use just blob. Im sending json objects to a websockets server.

Comment: did you find the solution